# multiple threads in for each loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently implementing a task that consumes lot of time for the execution.So, I have opted for threading. But I have a foreach loop in my thread in which I want to create multiple threads.
I was worried is this is the appropriate way to do it.

My code is similar to the following:

```
    Thread th= new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProcedure));
    th.IsBackground = true;
    th.Start();

   public void ThreadProcedure()
   {
    //I have datatable here
    foreach(DataRow in mytable.rows)
    {
    //here I want to create a multiple threads, say like

    //Thread1 on which I want to run method1
     Method1(dr["Column1"].ToString());
    //Thread2 on which I want to run method2
     Method2(dr["Column2"].ToString());
    //Thread3 on which I want to run method3
       Method3(dr["Column3"].ToString());
    }
  }
```

Inside my foreach I am running some methods by passing the values of the cells in datarow.

Comment: what problems are you having

Comment: You generally want to create your threads *outside* of the loop, then give each one of the threads part of the work to do. As Matthew suggests, Parallel.ForEach is designed for this.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am trying to implement parallel.foreach which executes much faster than foreach but unable to implement it on datarows of my datatable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your threads are not related, the easiest way is likely to use the [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)

If the *are* related and you need specified `wait` behavior, you should consider using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

**EDIT:** If you want to invoke methods in parallel from within your loop you can use [Parallel.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx) but it seems easier to do it on the parent collection of rows (unless you have very few rows or the rows are dependent on each others' actions)

Comment: @Matthew I have been trying alot to implement parallel.foreach but was unable to handle it properly, can u suggest me any suggestion

Comment: @Cherry edit your original question to show what you tried when you tried to use Parallel.Foreach, we can then tell you what went wrong for it not to work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am trying to call three methods which takes values of the datacolumns in my datarow. and i want to run each of them in a single thread.But was unable get an idea how to implement it. Hope you understand after looking at the updates i made for the question

Comment: @Matthew Your suggestions helped me ,solve it.thnx man..Parallel.ForEach has worked for me

Comment: @Cherry glad I could help. Maybe you can post the code you ended up using?